# search query optimization Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I try to optimize the following queries on a table contains more than 1.2 millions of records .

***#1 - Execution time : 0.6605 , used for get the items***

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE MATCH (name,tags) AGAINST ('mytag' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 20
```

***#2 - Execution time : 0.5186 , used for the pagination system ***

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `videos` WHERE MATCH (name,tags) AGAINST ('mytag' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

**Stucture of my table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `videos`;
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`name_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`categories` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`embed` tinytext,
`description` text,
`tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`hd` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
`views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`likes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`dislikes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`cover` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `categories` (`categories`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `tags` (`tags`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1273355 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

***Any solution for have fast responses for each queries ?***

*Best regards*

Comment: Hmm no answers ... ?

Comment: lol be patient. 24 min and you are demanding an answer. We dont work for you.

Comment: and learn how to ask question. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: and Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: I am not familiar with `MATCH() AGAINST()` so what if you switch it to use a `LIKE` clause instead? Have you created any indexes for the `name` or `tags` fields?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes should be loaded into RAM, but MyISAM has a finite-sized buffer to store indexes. You may need to increase the size of your MyISAM index buffer with the `key_buffer_size` configuration option.

I have no idea what your server specs are. It must be a pretty underpowered server, because I've done tests with a MySQL fulltext index on 7.4 million rows of data, and had queries execute in 16 milliseconds. This was on a Macbook Pro, and a real server should be even faster.

See my presentation about fulltext search in MySQL here: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

Comment: I'll switch to elastic search , it's better ^^

Comment: Elastic Search uses Lucene internally, the same as Solr. So performance and scalability should be comparable.